# Not able to use React 16 library in react 17

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

Tried using library made in react 16 in react 17, Getting
[cannot get original source of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vViRb.png) in terminal
whereas Console say
[Minified React error 188](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjYfR.png).
which is "Unable to find node on an unmounted component"

I am not using any useState in accessing page

I have checked related questions, still haven't found any working solution.

It works fine in react 16

To reproduce - I have been implementing widget created in react 16 in react 17

Note - I have referred to this, and followed all, nothing worked for me
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20131

Here's my package.json
[package.json of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaTX4.png)

and
[package.json of library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsbwy.png)

Reference to reproduce- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20131#issuecomment-828273745

Comment: Please use a development version of React for debugging, not the minified production version. [The error](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=188) is "Unable to find node on an unmounted component.".

Comment: The "cannot get original source" error is likely not related to what you're seeing in the browser; it's just Webpack not being able to do sourcemap related things.

Comment: what can be done to resolve this ?

Comment: What is the library you're talking about, anyway? Unless it explicitly does non-react or `UNSAFE` things, it should work just fine with React 17.

Comment: It's private from the company I work for. Which shows widgets.

Comment: Regarding its code, it uses React.createElement and display modal

Comment: Well, is it possible you have two React versions in your `node_modules` tree? That will cause conflicts.

Comment: updating the post with package.json

Comment: I didn't ask for screenshots of package.json – I asked whether there are multiple versions of React in your actual node_modules tree.

Comment: no there's one with react 17